# useSWR with `revalidateOnMount: false` vs useSWRMutation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swr

What is the difference between

```
const {mutate} = useSwr(url, fetcher, {revalidateOnMount: false});
mutate();
```

and

```
const {trigger} = useSWRMutation(url, fetcher);
trigger();
```

Docs say: revalidateOnMount: enable or disable automatic revalidation when component is mounted

But on revalidateOnMount = false, no requests are made until mutate is called. Which is same as useSWRMutation.